# Google Drive on iOS and "invalid_grant"

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have an iOS app that uses Google Drive to sync some files.  The app was working fine up until a couple of months ago (it uses iCloud by default for syncing so it wasn't until recently that I learned the Google Drive since was no longer working).

The error I'm getting is:

> An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={json={
>       error = "invalid_grant";
>   }, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f722220 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f67 72616e74 220a7d>}

The OAuth part sets to be OK and I think I'm authorized to access the user's Google Drive.  The error happens when I try to list the files at the top level to see if I need to create a special directory for my app.

```
- (void)createGoogleDocumentsDirIfNeeded:(id<GoogleServiceDelegate>)delegate
{
NSString *parentID = @"root";

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents and title = '%@' and trashed != true", parentID, APP_NAME];

[googleService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                      GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                      NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         if ( files.items.count == 0)
         {
             NSLog(@"Creating google documents dir: %@", APP_NAME);
             [self createGoogleDocumentsDir:delegate];
         }
         else
         {
             GTLDriveFile *file = [files objectAtIndexedSubscript:0];
             self.googleDocumentsID = file.identifier;

             NSLog(@"Directory exists: %@; fileID = %@", APP_NAME, googleDocumentsID);
             [delegate googleDocumentsDirCreated:YES];

         }
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

}

The error is displayed in the last NSLog().

I'm pretty convinced that something has change on Google's side that is causing this.  I've reverted to code to a point where I know it worked before and it is still failing.

Possibly I've made some change in our Google Developer's Console that is causing this, but I can't see what.

It is also the case that the Google API Dashboard still shows some successful accesses, so it seems this is not failing for everyone.

Any thoughts as to what could be going on?  The "invalid_grant" error seems pretty generic and web searches show it happens in lots of situations.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, there could be a variety of explanations.

Some to check are:-

1. has the user withdrawn his permission
2. are you using an expired refresh token
3. is the phone's clock accurate

Answer (score 0):

Read https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

> The URL used when authenticating a user is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth. This endpoint is accessible over SSL, and HTTP connections are refused.

Only for httpS connects for now

Comment: But I'm not writing a web app.  This is using Google's SDK's for iOS.  After some research it seems like perhaps the old SDKs are no longer compatible with the service.  Could it be that the old SDK are not using https:?  I tried upgrading to the new SDKs but they are in a bit of a mess right now.  I'm going to wait a few months and try again.